# Industry awards for software engineering

Tags: software-industry, software-development

In many industries such as sales awards are common place. For easy to quantify metrics such as sales numbers it eases the management burden of giving awards for things like 'top sales person'. What awards are available for software engineers?

Comment: Are you looking exclusively for awards that are 1) internal and 2) for individuals or are you asking if there are awards that apply to software development in general?

Comment: I'm looking more to professional awards in general. I'm not looking for examples for academics such as IEEE awards or the Turing award. I used the sales example as a contrast for software engineering as it is easy to see the difference between the two and why it is hard to quantify development efforts.

Answer (score 9):

**I would argue that this would likely be destructive**

Sales is largely an individual sport. Development is a team one. As a result there are fewer awards for it as individual performance is harder to determine. Having devs compete against each other would undermine a lot of development work.

It also doesn’t help that engineering is often considered a cost by the businesspeople who run the organization.

Comment: yes, gaming it will weaken a team, and quantifying work will be very difficult.

Comment: Also exploitable for profit, like the "Who's Who of ___"

Comment: Competitive team sports still exist though, they're just competing with an entire team instead of individually. You can argue that competition is destructive in general (either opinion can be justifiable), but I wouldn't particularly make a distinction between the validity of individual and team-based competition.

Comment: this. in fact, if a company would offer such awards as in sales, that would mean I'm looking for another company. There is a reason sales people have a bad name and I wager this is part of them.

Answer (score 5):

> What awards are available for software engineers?

Bonuses, favourable reviews, added responsibility, additional training and certification. The normal stuff. Sales is a very different scenario and sometimes the pay is low and the awards are what they really work for and often compete for. This approach won't work with professional engineers.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t think there is any universally quantifiable metric to score developers on
Sales example is not a good one to compare development against being a solo, specific target industry.

Software development is always a team effort, that includes not only actual coders, team leaders and system analysts but also Business Analysts, Project Managers and such

Each  level of responsibility contributes to a project success or failure.

Also, there are lots of tools and technologies that results can be achieved with.